# Prolog: get all possible values of a variable

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I'm Following [Prolog Tutorial 2.1](https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_1.html).

Program

```
adjacent(1, 2).
adjacent(1, 3).
adjacent(1, 4).

main:-
    adjacent(1, R),
    write(R).
```

prints `2`.

But it supposes to print a list of possible values according to the tutorial:

```
?- adjacent(1,2). 
yes 
?- adjacent(1,3). 
no 
?- adjacent(1,R). 
R = 2 ; 
R = 3 ; 
R = 4 ; 
no
```

I try again in repl only to get the same result:

```
?- adjacent(1, R).
R = 2 .
```

How could I get/print a list of possible values of a variable?

Comment: You pressed <kbd>Return</kbd>! Press <kbd>Space</kbd> to get the next answer.

Comment: `adjacent(1,3).` should have resulted in `yes`. There's something you didn't do quite right which isn't visible.

Comment: @false I make it in repl, but how could get those value when running the program as a script like `swipl -q -f Adjacent.pl -t main`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swipl, library([apply](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=apply)) is - by default - autoloaded, so you can write

```
main:-
    forall(adjacent(1, R), (write(R),nl)).
```

note: Action is a conjuction, just for to illustrate the proper syntax required. For any practical purpose, `main :- forall(adjacent(1, R), writeln(R)).` could be better.

Answer (score 0):

You need a failure-loop:

```
adjacent(1, 2).
adjacent(1, 3).
adjacent(1, 4).

main :-
    adjacent(1, R),
    write(R), nl,
    fail.
main.
```

This is a basic programming technique in Prolog. fail/0 will force backtracking, so next adjacent/2 solution is explored (and so on). Second clause to main/0 prevents the loop itself from failure.

Answer (score 0):

after Prolog prints `R = 2;`, you can press "r", "n", [TAB] or [SPACE] to show the next results.
I don't know how that works with `write(R).` but that is not in the code from the tutorial so I think that's supposed to be the trick